# Strip off text before and after a value that matches a pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This little bit of JavaScript jQuery code below shows something like this for each value in the array:

```
<span class="label">oranges</span>
```

Where oranges would be the value that is different in each item.

I need to strip everything off so that I have just the `oranges` part in a variable?

http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/kw7uwu2y/

```
var taskAssignedUserDataArray = [
    '<span class="label">oranges 1</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 2</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 3</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 4</span>'];


var value = taskAssignedUserDataArray;

$.each(value,function(i){
    alert(value[i]);
    value[i] = $('<p>' + value[i] + '</p>').text()
});
```

Comment: What is the relation of `each` and `span`?

Comment: Are you using `.html()` to get the parent? If so, try `.text()` instead.

Comment: so do you basically turn the <span> into a <p>?

Comment: Please provide us with a little more information, how are you currently trying to access the value?

Comment: Updated with better example.  I pulled this out of part of some code used for the Select2 jQuery library.

Comment: You want to get only the inner html ("oranges") from all instances of a span with the class "label"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, see below

```js
var taskAssignedUserDataArray = [
    '<span class="label">oranges 1</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 2</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 3</span>',
    '<span class="label">oranges 4</span>'];


var value = taskAssignedUserDataArray;

$.each(value,function(i){
    alert(value[i].replace(/(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)/i, '$2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The results are
Oranges 1
Oranges 2
Oranges 3
Oranges 4

Comment: Great, coronator1999 posted first but since your answer is more complete with working demo which could help others more as the selected answer, I choose yours,  However do you know which would be more performant yours or coronator1999 answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions for removing HTML tag from variable along with replace method.

```
var newval = value[i].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

So.. I wanted to have fun with an answer. The answer by coronator is probably the best and most right answer...

But!! Cause I was curious if I could do it this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/kw7uwu2y/4/

Basically ::

```
var taskAssignedUserDataArray = $('span.label');


var value = taskAssignedUserDataArray;

$.each(value,function(){
    $(this).html('<p>'+$(this).text()+"</p>");
    var children = $(this).children('p');
    $(this).after(children)
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: :/ That's one way to do it haha, clever